# joomla article list with thumbnails

Tags: joomla1.5

## Title of the article    Author              Hits

1     Restaurante Al Cambio   Administrator       24

2     Convencion Verano 2010  Administrator       50

3     Ile Aiye & Ketubara     Administrator       54

I have article list with this format but I want small thumbnail to each article instead of numbers 1,2,3,....If anyone have idea about component/plugin/module available in joomla  to show article list with thumbnails instead of numbers inform me immediately.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a template override. You'd need to write some code to pull the images out of the article and remove the order list. If this is a Section listing or Category listing you would need to edit either

For a category listing:
template/[your template]/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php and
template/[your template]/html/com_content/category/blog.php

or for a section listing:
template/[your template]/html/com_content/section/blog_item.php and
template/[your template]/html/com_content/section/blog.php

Or you could just use K2, it has built in support for article images.